# Can I pass a function as an argument in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Can I pass a function as an argument in CMake?

I'm writing a function wrapper to easily generate multiple objects, but when it comes to some features that simply differs in the `add_executable` or `cuda_add_executable`, `add_library` or `cuda_add_executable` stuffs, it's hard to write simple code.

What I'm aiming to achieve is that, users may pass the `add_executable` function via a variable so that they can use customized ones, like:

```
add_executable_wrap(TARGET "demo" SRCS "src/main.cu" INCLUDES "include" FN "cuda_add_executable")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function in CMake whose name is stored in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405122/how-to-call-a-function-in-cmake-whose-name-is-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake invoking dynamic macro name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572101/cmake-invoking-dynamic-macro-name)

Comment: Thx, let's close it.